# Error: Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

Why it happens? Here is my code to read dictionary from bin file

```
public static object LoadObject()
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists("D://my.bin"))
        {
            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("D://my.bin");
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            Dictionary<int, Question> deserializedObject = (Dictionary<int, Question>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            return deserializedObject;
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: If an exception occurs, your method returns nothing. It has to always return an `object`.

Comment: What's the purpose of your empty `catch` block? What do you hope that will do?

Answer (score 4):

Your method is suppose to return an object of type `object`, but you are only returning inside the `try` block and that too from inside an `if` statement. So if your condition fails, your method will not return anything. Also if there is an exception in try block, before returning the object then your method would fail to return anything. That is why you are getting the error. You can fix that by returning `null` from outside of `try / catch` block.

```
public static object LoadObject()
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists("D://my.bin"))
        {
            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("D://my.bin");
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            Dictionary<int, Question> deserializedObject = (Dictionary<int, Question>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            return deserializedObject;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

        //log exception
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Although this will will fix your error, but you should look for other option like throwing an exception if the file is not found, or returning an error object.

Answer (score 2):

You need a return also if your code raises an exception or if the condition File.Exists is not met
However, as is, there is no point in catching the exception. If you don't do anything with it, let it bubble at the upper level

```
public static object LoadObject()
{
    if (File.Exists("D://my.bin"))
    {
        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("D://my.bin");
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        Dictionary<int, Question> deserializedObject = (Dictionary<int, Question>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
        return deserializedObject;
    }
    else
        throw FileNotFoundException("There is no file named", "D:\\my.bin");
}
```

Comment: the error is still the same

Comment: I would not just blindly return `null` just because I'm "lacking a better option." I would return `null` when I want to return `null`. If I'm "lacking a better option," I would look for the fundamental flaw in the design of my method.

Comment: @AntP I disagree. Of course the best path is always to find the flaw in your design, but it is not prohibited to return null from a method. In this case you could also design this method to return null if the file doesn't exist. However I prefer to throw an exception and let the caller handle the situation

Comment: I didn't say it's prohibited - or even suggest it's bad - to return null from a method; it is, however, bad to return any value just because you're not sure what else to do. If there's no valid execution path, then throwing an exception - as you say - is the correct thing to do; not just return null and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, all the code paths must return a value. You have two conditions where no value is returned:

1. If the file does not exist.
2. If an exception is thrown.

Change the code to:

```
try
{
    if (File.Exists("D://my.bin"))
    {
       ...
       return deserializedObject;
    }
}
catch
{

}
return null; // Or return an empty dictionary with:
             // return new Dictionary<int, Question>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public static object LoadObject()
 {
   try
     {
       if (File.Exists("D://my.bin"))
         {
            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("D://my.bin");
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            Dictionary<int, Question> deserializedObject = (Dictionary<int, Question>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            return deserializedObject;
         }
     }
    catch
       {
         return null;
       }
     return null;
 }
```